What's a proper WMI Filter Query for Computers without a TPM?
I have two GPO's that affect Bitlocker. One GPO for computers with TPM and one for computers without TPM. Then we structure out our AD OU where the departments are under the TPM ou or the No TPM ou which has the correlated GPO linked to that OU. Here's a visual breakdown.

Computers
TPM (TPM GPO linked)
Finance
Business
No TPM ("No TPM" GPO linked)
Finance
Business
Users
etc...

Instead of having an OU for "TPM" and "No TPM" and then redundantly having the same departments under each parent OU, I want to have a WMI filter that will apply the No TPM GPO to the appropriate computers.
Some recommendations I have seen were to query the Win32_SystemDriver class but the names can be different and sometimes the state isn't always stopped if they don't have a TPM.
I tried querying the Win32_Tpm class in root\CIMv2\Security\MicrosoftTpm, but there is no data at all if the computer does not have a TPM. Which my understanding is that if no records are returned that would be result in the WMI filter NOT matching. So I don't think I'll be able to query that class.
Feel free to let me know if my thinking on the aforementioned is wrong, but does anyone know a accurate WMI Filter Query for computers that do not have a TPM module?

What are you trying to configure on the non-TPM machines? If it's something relatively simple like a couple of registry keys or similar, you might want to try using Preferences and item-level targeting.
In the Targeting Editor window, you can select the WMI Query item and enter the query that'll return a result if TPM is installed. Then in the Item Options menu, you can select the Is Not option (or press F8).
I haven't done much with TPM, but if there's some registry item you can test for using the "Registry Match" instead of a WMI query, that tends to be faster. The same Is Not option is there as for WMI and the other items available in Targeting Editor.
If it's a complex set of policies you want to apply to the non-TPM machines via a specific GPO, you might need to scope it to an AD group and add your non-TPM machines to that. Obviously there's some way that you're moving TPM and non-TPM machines to different OUs - a similar process could be done to add them to a security group.
Unfortunately, though, I believe that you need to match something for a WMI filter to work at the GPO level.

We have two settings that are different in our Non-TPM GPO versus our TPM GPO. The Non-TPM GPO has the following set
--Windows Components/Bitlocker Drive Encryption/Operating System Drives--
"Disallow standard users from changing the PIN or Password - Enable"
"Require additional authentication at startup - Enable"
The TPM GPO does not have those settings.
I need these settings to be in place on all non-TPM computers. I can do the OU/computer group structure to link the proper GPO, but in case we have a computer that slips through the cracks and doesn't get added I want WMI to handle it.

So instead of using a group policy template, you can just set registry preferences scoped to the non-TPM machines. One to set a DWORD value of 1 for DisallowStandardUserPINReset under HKLM\Software\Policies\Microsoft\FVE. And a DWORD of 1 for UseAdvancedStartup under the same key (plus EnableBDEWithNoTPM?). You can check exactly which the values that correspond to the policies you want at: https://admx.help/?Category=Windows_11_2022&Policy=Microsoft.Policies.VolumeEncryption::ConfigureAdvancedStartup_Name

To double-check which reg keys are enabled when the policy is applied, you could apply a GPO with the correct settings via the policy template to a test machine. Then inspect that registry key on the test machine to verify which values were configured. Then obviously configure another test policy, this time by applying registry preferences with those values rather than the GPO template, and see if a new test machine behaves the same.
